# Agenda - dynamically change selected day

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm having trouble to dynamically change the selected day. For example, I want to change selected day to today when leaving the screen; I don't want to have other selected day than today when leaving... How can I do that? I'm using the agenda.
Also, I want to change the selected day when the user clicks on some button in that screen. My agenda list date is not changed at all if I just set the state for selectedDay...

My code for now;

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.props.navigation.addListener('didBlur', (playload)=>{
      console.log(playload);

     this.onDayPress(Moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString());
   });
}
```

My agenda:

```
<Agenda
  // the list of items that have to be displayed in agenda. If you want to render item as empty date
  // the value of date key kas to be an empty array []. If there exists no value for date key it is
  // considered that the date in question is not yet loaded
  items={this.state.items2}
  // callback that gets called when items for a certain month should be loaded (month became visible)
  //loadItemsForMonth={}
  // callback that fires when the calendar is opened or closed
  onCalendarToggled={(calendarOpened) => {}}
  // callback that gets called on day press
  onDayPress={this.onDayPress.bind(this)}
  // callback that gets called when day changes while scrolling agenda list
  onDayChange={(day)=>{
    this.setState({day: day})
    console.log('OnDayChange: ' + day);
  }}
  // initially selected day
  //selected={ Moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString()}
  //selected={'2018-02-20'}
  selected={this.state.selectedDay}
  // Minimum date that can be selected, dates before minDate will be grayed out. Default = undefined
  minDate={this.state.minDate}
  // Maximum date that can be selected, dates after maxDate will be grayed out. Default = undefined
  maxDate={this.state.maxDate}
...
```

onDayPress method;

```
onDayPress(day) {
    //console.log('Predn zamenjam selected day: ' + this.state.selectedDay);

    if(day.dateString === undefined) {

      if(day !== undefined) {
        //console.log('day: ' + day);
        this.setState({
          selectedDay: day
        });
        return true;
      }

    }

    this.setState({
      selectedDay: day.dateString
    }); 

    this.getNextThreeDays(day.dateString);
    this.getQuotes(day.dateString);
  }
```

### Environment

- `npm ls react-native-calendars`: 1.19.4
- `npm ls react-native`: ^0.55.4

Answer (score 3):

Few years late but managed to solve this using refs

```js
import React, { createRef } from 'react';

const agendaRef = createRef();
```

When rendering the agenda include the reference

```jsx
<Agenda
  ref={agendaRef}
  ...
/>
```

For the `onPress` function for the button include the call to `chooseDay`

```js
const date = '2020-10-01' // the date you want to go to
agendaRef.current.chooseDay(date)
```

It should animate as if the date button was tapped

Comment: I'm getting `undefined is not a function` for the ref

Comment: Did you defined `const agendaRef = createRef();` outside the function or class or inside? You should define it outside as global. If it doesn't work for you please share your code please.